# A few counterexamples in the convergence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm studying the various types of convergence for sequences of real valued functions defined on measure spaces: pointwise convergence a.e. , convergence in $L^p$ norm, weak convergence in $L^p$, and convergence in measure. It is quite complicated to see exactly what the relationships between the various types of convergence are, here is a diagram that shows the possibilities (when dealing with measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$, with $1 \leq p < \infty$ ; note that areas (2) and (3) are empty when the space has finite measure, since in this case convergence a.e. implies convergence in measure). [image]

Working mainly with [these](http://web.math.unifi.it/users/magnanin/Istit/a3gsm11.pdf) lecture notes (sorry, they're in Italian... anyway, many examples are on pages 124, 125), I have managed to fill all except the shaded areas in the diagram. So here are my questions:

> > Do there exist sequences of real valued funcions, defined on measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$ that:
> >
> > - $(6)$ converge in measure, but not a.e. and not weakly in $L^p$ for some $p \in [1, +\infty)$
> > - $(7)$ converge in measure, weakly in $L^p$, but not a.e. and not in $L^p$
> > - $(8)$ converge in measure, weakly in $L^p$, a.e., but not in $L^p$

I don't really know if I'm missing something stupid here, or if these examples are really tricky to find (or perhaps they don't exist). 
 Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you list here all the examples in the link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For (8), if $p>1$, let $a_n=\frac{1}{m(B(0,1/n))^{1/p}}$, and take $f_n=a_n\chi_{B(0,1/n)}$.

For (6) and (7), first let $A_1, A_2,A_3,\ldots$ be a sequence of subsets such that $m(A_n)\to 0$ and every element of the domain is in $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

For (6), let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\displaystyle{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n m(A_n)^{1/p}=+\infty}$, and take $f_n=a_n\chi_{A_n}$.

For (7), if $p>1$, let $\displaystyle{b_n=\frac{1}{m(A_n)^{1/p}}}$, and take $f_n=b_n\chi_{A_n}$.