# Counterexamples in convergence in $M(X)$ and $C_0(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to get a good handle on analysis counterexamples as they relate to convergence in $M(X)$ and $C_0(X)$. Awhile back there was an excellent discussion of pointwise convergence, convergence in $L^p$ norm, weak convergence in $L^p$ and convergence in measure, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118751/a-few-counterexamples-in-the-convergence-of-functions).

How about a similar set of counterexamples for $M(X)$ and $C_0(X)$? Here we have the notions of vague convergence, weak* convergence, convergence in norm (where the norm of a complex Radon measure is its total variation).

How about these counterexamples (asked in Folland or a variation therein):

a) $\mu_n\to 0$ vaguely, but $\|\mu_n\|=|\mu|(X)|\nrightarrow 0$.

b) $\mu_n\to 0$ vaguely, but $\int f\ d\mu_n\nrightarrow \int f\ d\mu$ for some bounded measurable $f$ with compact support.

c) $\mu_n\ge 0$ and $\mu_n\to 0$ vaguely, but $\mu_n((-\infty,x])\nrightarrow \mu((-\infty,x])$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

d) $\{f_n\}\in C_0(X)$ converges weakly to some $f$, but not pointwise.

---

Any links to conceptual ways of internalizing these different notions of convergence, in addition to providing counterexamples, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Let me define the notions of convergence as Folland does:

*Vague convergence* means convergence with respect to the vague topology on $M(X)$, which is also known as the weak* topology on $M(X)$, which means that $\mu_\alpha\to \mu$ iff $\int f\ d\mu_\alpha\to \int f\ d\mu$ for all $f\in C_0(X)$.

*Weak convergence* means that convergence on $X$ with respect to the topology generated by $X^*$.

The norm on $M(X)$ is given by the *total variation*, so that $\|\mu\|=|\mu|(X)$, so that convergence with respect to this norm means that $|\mu_n-\mu|(X)\to 0$.

Incidentally I find it awkward working with the total variation in such discussions of convergence because there is no clear geometry to work with as far as I can tell; the definition is rather too abstract for me at the moment.

Comment: Can you give your definitions for the various modes of convergence?  Authors sometimes vary in their usage.  Anyway, as a hint, consider $\delta_{x_n}$, a measure with a unit point mass at some $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and consider what happens as $x_n \to x$ or $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, Nate. I added the definitions to the question - I am using Folland as my guide through analysis. I actually considered that point mass measure, possibly from some other resource, but I can't find a way to make it work with the definitions.

Comment: So let's start with part (a).  Let $\mu_n = \delta_n$ be a point mass at $n$.  I claim that this sequence has the desired properties.  Can you verify this from the definitions?  If not, where do you get stuck?

Comment: The total variation of a complex Radon measure is the positive measure $|\nu|$, where $d|\nu|=|f| d\mu$ for $\mu$ a positive measure, where by the Riesz Representation theorem $f$ is in $C_0(X)$. So if $\mu_n=\delta_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, s.t. $|\mu_\alpha|(X)\to |\mu|(X)$ this means that for some $f\in C_0(X)$, $f(n)=|\mu_\alpha|=\int |f_\alpha|\ d\mu \nrightarrow \int |f|\ d\mu=|\mu|(X)=0$, but $\delta_n\to 0$ vaguely since for all $f\in C_0(X)$ for $n$ large $\int f\mu_n$ is small.

How is that?

Comment: Your definition of total variation seems a little confused, you might want to review the definition.  However it is worth noting that for a positive measure $|\mu| = \mu$.  So in fact we have $\lVert \delta_n \rVert = 1$ for all $n$.  It is also worth knowing that for a complex Radon measure $\mu$, $\lVert \mu \rVert = \sup\{\int f \,d\mu : f \in C_0(X), \lVert f \rVert_\infty \le 1\}$, i.e. the total variation norm is the operator norm in $C_0(X)^*$.

Comment: I was taking the definition straight out of Folland of total variation. Can you be specific where you think I messed up?

Comment: Folland defines the total variation of $\nu$ (page 93) as the unique positive measure $|\nu|$ such that if $\mu$ is a positive measure, $f$ is a measurable function, and $d\nu = f d\mu$, then $d|\nu| = |f| d\mu$.  I don't see why you are bringing in the Riesz representation theorem, and I don't understand what $\mu_\alpha$ and $\mu$ are supposed to be.  Unfortunately this is not a great forum for working through details like this.